# Hide or Remove icons from Context Menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu

I find a load of topics on how to remove or edit items from the context menu in Windows, but nothing on how to hide or remove icons from the context menu to make it tidier and more compact looking.

to go from something like this

[image]
to something more like this
[image]

is there something in the registry I can put in under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` entry to make this happen, ie; `DWORD NoIcons = 1`?

Answer (score 1):

For static context menu items, not powered by context menu handler shell extension, you can remove the icon from the registry.

For example, to remove the icon for Personalize, remove the value named `Icon` in this registry key:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Personalize

Note that you need to [take ownership](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-of-registry-keys-and-assign-full-permissions/) of the key first.

For Display settings, here:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Display

For context menu items added by shell extensions (Dlls), I'm not sure if you can remove those icons.